# Update Salesforce field before record saves

Tags: salesforce

My goal is to have a hyperlink that is clickable in mobile app that we use.

I have a custom object Quote with two fields:
Exit_Report_URL__c that is URL(255) and 
Exit_Report__c that is Formula (Text)

Exit_Report__c constructs a hyperlink from data on the quote that is used to open a new tab with a Google Form with Pre-filled Ink. This works great on desktop web browsers.

However, it is not clickable in the mobile app that we use.
Exit_Report_URL__c, on the other hand, displays a nice clickable button, but my users have to copy the links from the Exit_Report__c formula field and manually paste them in the Exit_Report_URL__c for my mobile users to be able to use them easily.

I want Exit_Report_URL__c to be read only and updated automatically any time the Project record changes.

I tried to use Process Builder, but could not save the record after making changes with the process activated.

Is there a better way to accomplish what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the `HYPERLINK()' feature of a text formula field for this.

```
HYPERLINK(
    Exit_Report__c 
,   'ExitReport'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a delayed action that populates the URL field based on a formula 1 hour later.